# Prolog code error

Tags: prolog

My code is supposed to output a schedule for a competetion the predicate `scheduleround2` is used to generate a list of `game(player1,player2,round)`.
however there is an error most probably with the unification for Z.

here is the code:

sample input:

```
schedule_round([player(alex,2), player(jane,5), player(djokovich,1), player(nadal,3), player(anderson,4), player(jack,6), player(nilson,7), player(pete,8)], R).
```

and the output should be

```
R=[game(pete,djokovich,quarter_final), game(nilson,alex,quarter_final), game(jack,nadal,quarter_final), game(jack,jane,quarter_final)]
```

What actually happens is that is computes forever producing nothing

```
%gets the maximum player rating 
maxf([H|T], R) :- maximum(T, H, R).

maximum([], R, R).
maximum([player(X,Y)|T], player(_,R), F) :-
    Y > R,
    maximum(T, player(X,Y), F).
maximum([player(_,Y)|T], player(Z,R), F) :-
    R > Y,
    maximum(T, player(Z,R), F).

%gets the minimum player rating
minf([H|T], R) :- minimum(T, H, R).

minimum([], R, R).
minimum([player(X,Y)|T], player(_,R), F):-
    Y < R,
    minimum(T, player(X,Y), F).
minimum([player(_,Y)|T], player(Z,R), F):-
    R < Y,
    minimum(T, player(Z,R), F).

%removes players who are scheduled from the list
del(X, [X|L], L).
del(X, [A|L], [A|L1]) :- del(X, L, L1).

%gets size of the list
size([], 0).
size([_|T], N) :- size(T, M), N is M+1.

%scheduling predicate
schedule_round(X, R) :-
    size(X, N),
    schedule_round2(N, X, R).

%helper
schedule_round2(0, _, []).
schedule_round2(N, H, Z) :-
    N2 is N-2,
    maxf(H, F),
    minf(H, B),
    del(F, H, L),
    del(B, L, J),
    append(Z, game(F, B, quarter_final), K), 
    schedule_round2(N2, J, K).
```

Comment: You didn't say what the error actually is. And what predicate clause is the error pointing to? The error message will tell you what line(s) of code are implicated.

Comment: actually it is not an error message but when it keeps processing the predicate schedule_round2 forever

Comment: What query did you enter that resulted in the infinite loop?

Comment: You don't need the `size` predicate. ISO prolog has `length/2` which gives you the length of a list: `length(List, N)`.

Comment: Your `del(X, [A|L], [A|L1]) :-...` needs to check that `X \== A`. Otherwise prolog will backtrack to and succeed on that clause even if `X` and `A` are the same. And I assume you are querying with a list of an even number of elements, but just in case, `schedule_round2(N, H, Z) :-...` should first check, `N > 1`.

Comment: all predicates work very wall including the del except for schedule_round2 and i think the problem is append part

Comment: @mbratch
the querry that resulted in infinite loop is
schedule_round([player(alex,2), player(jane,5), player(djokovich,1), player(nadal,3), player(anderson,4), player(jack,6), player(nilson,7), player(pete,8)], R).

Comment: any clue on how to solve this ??

Comment: I've provided a complete answer.

Comment: And your hunch about there being an issue with the `append/3` query was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the definition of `schedule_round`.

The termination case `schedule_round(0, _, []).` fails because the third argument in the recursive calls to `schedule_round` is always a non-empty list. Also, I the original `append/3` statement you have is indeed an issue. It will always fail after the first time around since your second argument isn't a list and should be `[game(F, B, quarter_final)]` rather than just `game(F, B, quarter_final)`. When `append` fails, the `schedule_round` code backtracks through the other predicate queries, comes up with another possible solution and fails `append` again... infinitely. In addition, what's being appended to what is flipped around. We want the recursive call to `schedule_round2` to be the tail of the solution for any given call, so the new element prepends to the tail giving the new solution in the current call.

So the "quick fix" would be to just change `schedule_round2` recursive clause to:

```
schedule_round2(N, H, Z) :-
    N2 is N-2,
    maxf(H, F),
    minf(H, B),
    del(F, H, L),
    del(B, L, J),
    append([game(F, B, quarter_final)], K, Z),
    schedule_round2(N2, J, K).
```

This will work, but it turns out you don't need the `append/3` since `append([X], In, Out)` is the same as `Out = [X|List]`. We can reduce this to:

```
%helper
schedule_round2(0, _, []).
schedule_round2(N, H, [game(F,B,quater_final)|Z]) :-
    N > 1,              % This ensures N2 won't go negative due to bad input
    N2 is N-2,
    maxf(H, F),
    minf(H, B),
    del(F, H, L),
    del(B, L, J),
    schedule_round2(N2, J, Z).  % Schedule round for rest of the list
```

This version will recurse with the third argument (the tail of the solution) to `schedule_round2` uninstantiated until it hits the base clause. At that point, the third argument (solution tail) will instantiate to `[]` and rewind your solution to the desired result on the recursive returns.

Here are a few other optional suggested changes:

(1) Your `minimum` and `maximum` assume that the values compared are never equal. Perhaps this is the case. But you might consider:

```
maximum([player(_,Y)|T], player(Z,R), F) :-
    R >= Y,
    ...
```

and

```
minimum([player(_,Y)|T], player(Z,R), F):-
    R =< Y,
    ...
```

(2) In `schedule_round2/3` I added the check for `N > 1`. It's not necessary if you always give it an even-parity list (which is what's expected) but if you did give it an odd-parity list, it will cause the predicate to fail gracefully rather than recurse on negative `N` for a very long time.

(3) Your `size/2` predicate is unnecessary since Prolog already provides a list length predicate, `length/2`.